# Why can't insert this simple formula into a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of simple VBA code in a sub:

```
Range("AB7").Formula = "=IF(1=1;1;0)"
```

for which I get the mystical *Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error*

Why On Earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a `,` instead of `;` in your formula.

Like this:

```
Range("AB7").Formula = "=IF(1=1,1,0)"
```

The formula bar in the Excel application itself uses your culture info. That defines if you should use `,` or `;`. In the VBA code for `Formula` you have to use `,`, regardless of culture settings.

As **findwindow** states in the comments on this answer; you can also use `FormulaLocal` which uses your culture settings.

```
Range("AB7").FormulaLocal = "=IF(1=1;1;0)"
```

Although I doubt the portability of that. If I have the culture settings for `;` and my workbook is distributed to another computer that uses `,`, I guess you get the same error. Based on that, I would recommend to use `Formula` and `,`.

Comment: `formula.local` will allow you to use `;`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Correct line would become `Range("A1").FormulaLocal = "=IF(1=1;1;0)"`

Comment: OMG. Thanks, Lars!
Weird thing is `thing.Formula = "=IF(" & temp & "=0;""not filled"";" & temp & ")"` did work in an other line written earlier.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this as an answer if your problem is fixed. I also tried your formula but I get the same error as in your question. And see findwindow's his comment; you can use `FormulaLocal` too.